# Olympiad question from BdMO secondary category

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image: question picture]

---

It find this question from 551 Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad (BdMO) problems book. I have no idea about how to approach this kind of problems, as I'm a beginner. Please help me solve it. And I am sorry if it's too easy.

Comment: Why don't you transcribe the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked me to help you solve it, so notice $PM=DM$, since they are both radii of the bottom circle, and $AD=DP$ since they are both radii of the upper circle. From that, you get that $\Delta ADM$ and $\Delta APM$ are congruent triangles.

From here, if you know basic trigonometry, you can just "plug and chug" to get the answer. If you get stuck here is a hint:

> b=5

Comment: how to use basic trigonometry here to get the value of a ?

Comment: It's pretty easy: $\sin\theta=|AD|/|AM|$, Pythagoras, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The triangles $ADM, APM$ are congruent because they have a side $AM$ in common, while $AD=AP=4$ and $PM=DM=2.$ So $\angle DMA=\angle AMP.$ So $\angle DMP=\angle DMA+\angle AMP=2\angle DMA.$

Now $\tan \angle DMA=AD/DM=4/2=2 .$ From the formula $\tan 2x=\frac {2\tan x}{1-(\tan x)^2},$ we have $\tan \angle DMP =\tan 2\angle DMA=-4/3.$ And $\angle PMC=\pi -\angle DMP,$ so $\tan \angle PMC=4/3.$

From the formula $\sec^2 x=1+\tan^2 x,$ we have $\cos \angle PMC=3/5.$

Let $P'$ be on $MC$ with $PP'\perp MC.$ Then $MP'=MP\cos \angle PMC=2(3/5)=6/5. $

The distance from $P$ to $AD$ is equal to $P'D,$ which is $P'M+MD=(6/5)+2=16/5=a/b.$